# Search in multidimensional array using regex in in Spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got the following table column named ***data*** with the following structure:

```
{
  "data":[
      {
        "id":"test_111",
        "sum":"10"
      },
      {
        "id":"skip",
        "sum":"74"
       }
    ]
  }
```

I want to extract all records that have at least 1 record in **data** object that has id which starts with **test_{d}** (where {d} is digits). Meaning that if i have another ***data*** record with the this value

```
 {
   "data":[
       {
          "id":"skip_this_too",
          "sum":"123"
        },
        {
          "id":"skip",
          "sum":"11"
         }
     ]
 }
```

I want to skip it. I have tried to use scala's **array_contains** function, but it cannot be implemented in multidimensional array. Also, if i try this condition:

```
WHERE data.data[0].id LIKE 'test_%'
```

It works, but i'm not sure how to implement the same condition to all of data elements. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: this is json and should use sclas function https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson  or spark approach https://www.databricks.com/blog/2015/02/02/an-introduction-to-json-support-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: what is type of data column? could you print the schema and add it to the question? `df.select("data").printSchema()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using higher-order function [`exists`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/#exists) along with [`rlike`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#rlike(literal:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) for what you need, as shown in the following example:

```
val json = """[
    {
        "row_id": 1,
        "data": [
            { "id": "test_111", "sum": "10" },
            { "id": "skip1", "sum": "74" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "row_id": 2,
        "data": [
            { "id": "test_XYZ", "sum": "20" },
            { "id": "skip2", "sum": "85" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "row_id": 3,
        "data": [
            { "id": "skip3", "sum": "96" },
            { "id": "test_2222", "sum": "30" }
        ]
    } 
  ]"""

val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(Seq(json).toDS)

df.show(false)
/*
+------------------------------+------+
|data                          |row_id|
+------------------------------+------+
|[{test_111, 10}, {skip1, 74}] |1     |
|[{test_XYZ, 20}, {skip2, 85}] |2     |
|[{skip3, 96}, {test_2222, 30}]|3     |
+------------------------------+------+
*/
```

To filter the dataframe based on existence of any `data.id` with the `test_[0-9]+` pattern:

```
df.
  where(expr("exists(data, d -> d.id rlike 'test_[0-9]+')")).
  show(false)
/*
+------------------------------+------+
|data                          |row_id|
+------------------------------+------+
|[{test_111, 10}, {skip1, 74}] |1     |
|[{skip3, 96}, {test_2222, 30}]|3     |
+------------------------------+------+
*/
```